# How to download a webpage with a URL query in Clojure?

Tags: url, clojure

I like that in Clojure I can read a webpage with `(slurp url)` the same way I read files stored on the local machine. But as soon as the URL contains a question mark followed by paramethers (`https://www.google.ru/search?q=clojure`) `slurp` returns error 400. Do I have to use another function? What is the simplest way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you'll need to encode the `=` yourself. try this:

```
(slurp "https://google.ru/search?q%3Dclojure")
```

Also note there have been encoding [issues](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-885) with the underlying `clojure.java.io/reader` (what `slurp` is using under the covers) in the past so check your clojure version as well.

It is worth noting however that `slurp` is pretty basic and I wouldn't recommend relying on it for anything other than really basic stuff or as a convenience for working with URL's. If you need to pull information from URL's in actual code, I would suggest you look at [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http), which is a full-featured http client library which will give you much more control than `slurp`.

Comment: Yes, I've looked into clj-http, but in I just don't want to deal with dependencies in a simple script. Encoding `=` worked, thanks!